# How to render angular4 universal with query parameter route

Tags: angular, webpack, universal

I'm trying to migrate angular 1.4 to angular4 universal for SEO purposes. Everything works well. I have one route.

confirm email after registration
http://localhost/confirmEmail/09393?code='xxxxxxxxx'

```
ngOnInit() {

    let param_id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    let param_code = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['code'];
    this.message = '';

    this.authService.getConfirmation(param_id, param_code)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            },
            error => {

            }
        );
  }
```

1. Looks like it gets rendered on the server and calls rest API getConfirmation.
2. once UI is rendered on the client it calls getconfirmation again.

Is there a way. I don't wanna call the rest API server side, just call it from the client code.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

check to see if global window object is present. then call rest api to get confirmed

ngOnInit() {

```
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      let param_id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
      let param_code = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['code'];
      this.message = '';
      this.getConfirmation(param_id, param_code);
  }
```

}